# query error - ambiguous column name (models included)

Tags: sql

I am trying to join two columns and getting the error:

```
Error when executing SQL query on database 'test': ambiguous column name: candidates2.id
```

This works:

```
SELECT * FROM candidates2
WHERE caniddates2.id = '1'
```

it returns the first record.

However this doesn't:

```
SELECT * FROM candidates2, jobs
JOIN candidates2
    ON (candidates2.id = jobs.candidate_id)
```

I am getting the error above.

What am I doing wrong?

The model for reference (in Python with SqlAlchemy):

```
class Candidate2(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'candidates2'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    candidate_id = Column(String(), unique=True)
    candidate_name = Column(String())
    candidate_email = Column(String())

    jobs = relationship("Jobs", back_populates='candidates')

class Jobs(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'jobs'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    job_name = Column(String())
    job_id = Column(String())

    candidate_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('candidates2.id'))
    candidates = relationship("Candidate2", back_populates = 'jobs')
```

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Remove `candidates2,` after `FROM`. You want to join `jobs` to `candidates2`. So `candidates2` should be mentioned right after `JOIN`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't  mix implicit join  and explict join   .. use  an inner join with proper On clause for a join

```
SELECT * 
FROM candidates2
JOIN jobs  ON candidates2.id = jobs.candidate_id
```

you have ambiguous column name because you have the column id in both the table for avoid this you need  alias eg:

```
SELECT candidates2.id as c_id,  jobs.id as j_id
FROM candidates2
JOIN jobs  ON candidates2.id = jobs.candidate_id
```